# How do i send an email from command prompt?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, command

Is there any way to send a simple email as such at linux terminal?

```
to: somebody@gmail.com
sub: Sending email from linux terminal
body: This is a short email sent from linux terminal
```

What kind of stack or smtp do i need to setup? How do I set them up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Version for terminal:

```
mail somebody@gmail.com
```

Version for shell scripts:

```
echo "This is a short email" | mail -n -s "Sending email" somebody@gmail.com
```

AFAIK typical Linux distribution install MTA (sendmail/postfix/exim/...) by default. If you have static public IP address then its quite possible you have a working self-configuration.

Configuration of MTA without static public IP is more tricky.